# assertJson and assertSee show call to a null member error

Tags: laravel, phpunit, laravel-5.1

I trying to develop a test for my APIs,

This is my code:

```
public function testFirstAPI()
    {
        $user = \User::find(1);
        $r = $this
            ->actingAs($user)
            ->json('put', route('updateUser'),['lock' => 'true']);
        $r->assertResponseStatus(200)->seeJson(['success' => true]);
    }
```

this test will work and when I use `$r->dump()` I can found the `success` in the response.

but I don't know why `seeJson` show this error:

```
Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException]
  Call to a member function assertJson() on null
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you are chaining  `assertResponseStatus()` first and it does not return a *fluent* object.

A solution would be to put it as the last assertion in the chain:

```
public function testFirstAPI()
{
    $user = \User::find(1);

    $this->actingAs($user)
        ->json('put', route('updateUser'), ['lock' => 'true'])
        ->seeJson(['success' => true])
        ->assertResponseStatus(200)
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I really had a headache for this problem